# How to add current image file name to a slider

Tags: javascript, slider

I'm new to Javascript and found this code on w3schools.com for adding a slider.

It works great but I need to add the current file name in between the next and previous buttons and I don't know how.

Here is the code I used:

**The HTML**

```
<div class="slideshow-container">
<div class="mySlides fade">
<div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
<img src="img1.jpg" style="width:100%">
<div class="text">Caption Text</div>
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
<div class="numbertext">2 / 3</div>
<img src="img2.jpg" style="width:100%">
<div class="text">Caption Two</div>
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
<div class="numbertext">3 / 3</div>
<img src="img3.jpg" style="width:100%">
<div class="text">Caption Three</div>
</div>

<a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
<a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
</div>
<br>

<div style="text-align:center">
<span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
<span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
<span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
</div>
```

**The CSS**

```
* {box-sizing:border-box}

/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
max-width: 1000px;
position: relative;
margin: auto;
}

.mySlides {
display: none;
}

 /* Next & previous buttons */
.prev, .next {
cursor: pointer;
position: absolute;
top: 0%;
width: 45%;
margin-top: -22px;
padding: 16px;
color: white;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 18px;
transition: 0.6s ease;
border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
right: 0;
border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}
.prev {
text-align: right;
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover, .next:hover {
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}

/* Caption text */
.text {
color: #f2f2f2;
font-size: 15px;
padding: 8px 12px;
position: absolute;
bottom: 8px;
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
}

/* Number text (1/3 etc) */
.numbertext {
color: #f2f2f2;
font-size: 12px;
padding: 8px 12px;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
}

/* The dots/bullets/indicators */
.dot {
cursor:pointer;
height: 13px;
width: 13px;
margin: 0 2px;
background-color: #bbb;
border-radius: 50%;
display: inline-block;
transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active, .dot:hover {
background-color: #717171;
}

/* Fading animation */
.fade {
-webkit-animation-name: fade;
-webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
animation-name: fade;
animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
from {opacity: .4}
to {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fade {
from {opacity: .4}
to {opacity: 1}
}
```

**The Javascript**

```
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
var i;
var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
  slides[i].style.display = "none";
}
for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
  dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
}
slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
}
```

So I changed the prev and next arrows to the top as that's where I need them to be.  I'm adding 3 menus as the images and I need it to say page 1 of 3, page 2 of 3, and page 3 of 3 depending on which menu they are on.  So I guess I will need to change the image file name to "page 1 of 3", "page 2 of 3", and "page 3 of 3" to make it work like I need it to.  So how can I show the current file name in between my  prev and next arrows?

I hope this all make's sense!  Any help would be appreciated!!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try getting the source of your image tag from within JavaScript and use that to update the caption text

```
var ctext = slides[slideIndex - 1].childNodes[1].getAttribute("src")
slides[slideIndex - 1].childNodes[2].innerHTML = ctext
```